# Why do I have to use close() to close a file?

Tags: c, operating-system

I'm learning some file functions and hence have a doubt.

I'm curious about why it is necessary to call `close()` to close a file? If I did not call `close()` after reading/writing a file, what things might happen? And if I did call `close()`,can I still use the file descriptor?

Comment: A bunch of answers below say that close() flushes buffers to disk. However, close() is a POSIX function and no such thing is true of POSIX close(). It only releases locks and frees resources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- If the file has any sort of buffering behind it it and you don't call close then you could potentially lose data.
- If the OS has limited resources (e.g. number of open files) then by not closing files you are wasting system resources.
- Using a descriptor once the file is closed is pointless at best, massive bug at worst (a bit like using memory after it has been freed)

Comment: Several answers here claim that buffers are flushed upon close() but in fact that is not true ... POSIX close() does no flushing and has no bearing on whether or when data is written to the device.

Answer (score 3):

The close() function closes the connection between the program and an open file identified by a handle.  Any unwritten system buffers are flushed to the disk, and **system resources used by the file are released**

The bolded part is the prime reason why a file should be closed

Closing a file has the following consequences:

1)The file descriptor is deallocated. 
2) Any record locks owned by the process on the file are unlocked. 
3) When all file descriptors associated with a pipe or FIFO have been closed, any unread data is discarded.

Comment: +1 Remarkably, this is the only answer here that does not erroneously assert that close() flushes data.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't close a file opened for reading it can be blocked for concurrent writes.
If you don't close a file opened for writing - you can loose a piece of last-written data which OS holds in the buffer.

And never use a descriptor of already closed file. This has no sense.

Answer (score 0):

When you write to a file using write() system call, it doesn't writes immediately to the file. So after your operations, you have to call close() so that the buffer is flushed to the file and changes persist.
After calling close(), you cannot use the file descriptor.

Comment: write() copies data from user space into system buffers. The system buffers will be flushed at the system's convenience or upon a sync(). close() has *no bearing* on the flushing of buffers. It only frees file locks and releases resources.

Answer (score 0):

Closing a file:
When done with a file, it must be closed using the function fclose().

```
fclose(ifp);
fclose(ofp);
```

Closing a file is very important, especially with output files. The reason is that output is often buffered. This means that when you tell C to write something out, e.g.,

```
fprintf(ofp, "Whatever!\n");
```

it doesn't necessary get written to disk right away, but may end up in a **buffer** in memory. This output buffer would hold the text temporarily:

Sample output buffer:

```
----------------------------------------------
| a | b  | c | W | h | a | t | e | v | e | r |
----------------------------------------------
| ! | \n |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
----------------------------------------------
|   |    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
----------------------------------------------
|   |    |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
----------------------------------------------
...
```

(The buffer is really just 1-dimensional despite this drawing.)

When the buffer fills up (or when the file is closed), the data is finally written to disk.

**Reference**: http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/

Comment: Slight corrections. Your answer _seems_ to indicate that files should be closed with `fclose` only. You can close files with `close` too. Its just that `fclose` takes in a file pointer and `close` takes a file descriptor. Also, many implementations flush the buffer when they encounter a newline character `\n`

Comment: The question is about close(), not fclose(). Nothing you wrote here is actually true of close(). And Pavan's statement is perhaps even worse ... fopen pairs with fclose and open (or creat) pairs with close; the difference isn't just between file pointers and file descriptors, it's between quite different abstractions/APIs (one of which may happen to be implemented via the other).

Answer (score 0):

- When you write into a file you write first into a buffer, some
  function call the flush and the data is written on to the file, but
  others just write into the buffer. When the buffer is full it flushes
  on to the file without any direct call for a flush. You can also
  flush whenever you want if you want to be sure.
- And you cannot use the file descriptor anymore after you closed it.